# System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException

Tags: vb.net

I have to make a program for this class that has me call a Multicast Delegate to write a string backwards, count the characters, and count the words.  I've got that all sorted out, but when I run it I get : System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException

I only just learned about delegates yesterday, so maybe there's something obvious that I missed.

```
Private Delegate Sub Words(ByVal input As String)
    Sub Main()
    Console.Title = "Fun with words"
    Console.WriteLine("Type some words below.")
    Dim Input As String = Console.ReadLine()
    Dim Display As [Delegate]
    Dim Backwards As Words
    Dim Length As Words
    Dim Wordcount As Words
    Backwards = New Words(AddressOf BackwardsFunc)
    Length = New Words(AddressOf LengthFunc)
    Wordcount = New Words(AddressOf WordcountFunc)
    Display = MulticastDelegate.Combine(Backwards, Length, Wordcount)
    Display.DynamicInvoke()

    Console.ReadKey() 'end
End Sub
Sub BackwardsFunc(ByVal Input As String)
    ' Backwards
    Console.Clear()
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan
    Console.WriteLine(Input)
    Console.ResetColor()
    Console.WriteLine("Backwards:")
    Dim Array() As Char = Input.ToCharArray
    Dim Stack As New Stack()
    For Each element As Char In Array
        Stack.Push(element)
    Next
    For Each element As Char In Stack
        Console.WriteLine(element)
    Next
End Sub
Sub LengthFunc(ByVal Input As String)
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Length: " & Input.Length)
End Sub
Sub WordcountFunc(ByVal Input As String)
    Dim Items As String() = Input.Split(New Char() {" "c})
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Words: " & Items.Length)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your delegate `Words` expects a parameter, but you don't provide one when you invoke your delegates.

When you invoke the MulticastDelegate, also provide the argument that the delegates have to use, like this:

```
Display.DynamicInvoke(Input)
```